# Jquery Validation dosen't work anymore after enabling client side validation

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation

To amliorate my application i have activeted the Client Side Validation and it works so fine, but unfortuly Some Jquery Form Validation has turned down and dosn't work any more :( 
This is my JS code:

```
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.ui.datepicker.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.ui.core.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.ui.widget.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("form").validate({
            rules: {
                idv: { required: true },
                dd: { required: true },
                df: { required: true },
                remise: { required: true }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

And this is my Form code :

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("Promo", "Agence", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "search_form" })) { %>

    <p>
        Matricule vehicule : <br />
        <%: Html.TextBox("idv")%> <br />
        De : <br />
        <%: Html.TextBox("dd")%> <br />
        Juqu'a  : <br />
        <%: Html.TextBox("df")%> <br />
        Remise : <br />
        <%: Html.TextBox("remise") %> % <br />
        Description : <br />
        <%: Html.TextArea("des", new {rows="4", cols="30" })%>
    </p>
    <input type="submit" value="Ajouter" class="button"/>            
<% } %>
```

In this form i dont need to use model, i'm using other model in this same page, The Jquery Validation was working so fine until i have activated The Validation Client side.

Comment: Define "doesn't work."  Do you get a console error in the web browser?  Is the jQuery code being called at all?  What happens when you debug it.  If the error is happening in your JavaScript code, then it's on the client-side.  Server-side view code isn't going to help much.  When you turned on client-side validation, something changed in the output that was being emitted to the browser.  Debug within the browser and try to find out what changed and how it was a breaking change.

Comment: No error showing but when i click on button submit the `Jquery.validation scrip`t is not excuted, this same script was working before i enable `client validation` in my app

Comment: So then what changed?  Enabling client-side validation dramatically changes the HTML that gets emitted to the browser.  Based on the description so far, there's a good chance that either your jQuery code is now failing to bind to an element (maybe the elements changed) or some other emitted code is stealing the binding (overriding `onclick` and marking the event as handled, perhaps).  You need to debug your client-side code.

Comment: That depends on your browser.  My personal client-side debugger of choice is Firebug in Firefox.  Recent versions of IE have development tools as well, as do Chrome and Safari.  As for how to properly use them, well, that's another story entirely.  I can't really teach you that in a few comments, it's something you'll have to learn.

Comment: I have made some test i think because there is some conflict betwen Form so i have made change `$(document).ready(function () { $("#form1").validate({` and in my form i have changed her name to `form1` but stell not working

Comment: Did you also add the ID to the form tag? using (Html.BeginForm("Promo", "Agence", FormMethod.Post, new {ID = "form1", @class = "search_form" })) {

Comment: yes, i have added the id but still not calling this function

Comment: I'have made some other debug and i found out that : `Microsoft's jQuery Validate Unobtrusive makes other validators skip validation`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verify that these two lines are in your web.config file in the `appSettings` section

```
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
```

And add this line to your layout

```
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Also modify your existing scripts so that they all use `src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/...`

Comment: The Client Validation work, but the other Script `Jquery.validate` dosn't work any more, when i click on submit the validation script is not called

Comment: No, u have repeated the same thing a have writed, and what u have puted is for side Client Validation, in my case it work, the problem is in Jquery validate function it dosn't work. do u get it now?

Comment: Your layout is missing the jquery.unobtrusive script, there are 3 scripts that have to be added to your layout, not just the 2 you have listed.

Comment: i have fugured that : `Microsoft's jQuery Validate Unobtrusive makes other validators skip validation` thats means my function is skipped automatcly so do u got an idea

Comment: well the thing I see next is .. the script is included on the layout page.. and causes the document to try to fire the validate script for the form when ready.. if included on a page with no form, that could be a problem. I suggest debugging that script in your browser's dev tools, IE9 dev tools, Chrome dev tools or Firebug for FireFox... set a breakpoint in the script but also check the console for any errors that may be thrown by the browser, that should help point you in the right direction

Comment: Up u inspeared me :) i have added new ContentHolder in my master page in head and in call here when i need ti use Unbrustive.js

Comment: Good job, if that helped please undo your downvote if you don't mind

Comment: Show me the changes you made by updating your question, it might help me int he future as well

Comment: No problem, In my master Page, Header Section, i have added this, `<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeaderAdd" runat="server" />` then in my page when i need to use `Unobtrusive.js` i do this : `<asp:Content ID="Content5" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeaderAdd" runat="server">
    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</asp:Content>`